# How to use non singleton controllers that get a model from a nested route

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple app that returns a model from a [child route](https://github.com/toranb/kanban-board-without-ember-data/blob/nonSingletonSpike/app/routes/todos/todo.js).

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        var store = this.get("store");
        return store.find("todo", params.todo_id);
    }
});
```

When my controller is a singleton (the default in ember today) it works fine. The child routes model hook is invoked and a model is bound to the controller/view/template as you'd expect.

The trick is that when I flip the singleton bit my model is suddenly dead /undefined from the very start. Today my [initializer](https://github.com/toranb/kanban-board-without-ember-data/blob/nonSingletonSpike/app/initializers/repositories.js#L7) looks like this.

```
import Wat from "kanban/controllers/todos/todo";

export function initialize(container, application) {
    application.register('controller:todos/todo', Wat, {singleton: true });
}
```

If you turn this from true to false the tests break /the child route never gets a model for that controller.

Is this supported in ember 1.10+ and if so what am I doing wrong here?

Here is the branch on github for more context (it's a simple example app to show this is or is not supported -hope the ember-cli app is minimal)

https://github.com/toranb/kanban-board-without-ember-data/tree/nonSingletonSpike

**Edit**

Note: when using the ember-inspector I noticed that when singleton was true (the default) I see 3 controllers after the app is rendered. But when I flip it to false I only see 2 controllers ... making me think the "false" option is not supported anymore

Yet when I add a function that listens to "init" in the controller itself I do see it's invoke and the stack shows controllerFor

```
controller = container.lookup('controller:' + name);
```

...being invoked from the ember internals.

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    x: function() {
        return true;
    }.on("init")
});
```

Comment: I don't know offhand, but your `unassigned` controller methods could be: `unassigned: Ember.computed.filterBy('model', 'status_code', 1),`